# Total distance of the object

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, trigonometry, definite-integrals

Suppose that an object is moving with $x = t\sin(\pi t/2)$. Find the total distance that it travels between the first and the third pass by origin(The first pass occurs when $t=0$).

My try: First we should solve $x=0$. So we get $t=0, 2, 4$. Then we take derivative and equals to zero $$v= \sin(\pi t/2) + \pi t/2\cos(\pi t/2) = 0\\ \implies \tan(\pi t/2) = -\pi t/2$$I'm unable to solve this equation analytically.

Comment: The total distance is the length of curve $x$ from $t=0$ into $t=3$, right?

Comment: [WolframAlpha can't get a nice answer for you](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%28pi*t%2F2%29%2Bpi*t%2F2*cos%28pi*t%2F2%29%3D0). Strictly speaking, that doesn't mean that it can't be done, but it really lowers the odds.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the equation $\tan x + x =0$ does not permit exact analytical solutions. However, good algebraic approximations are still available.

For example, the first-order approximations for the first and second positive roots can be expressed as

$$x_1= \frac{2\pi}{3} + \frac{3\sqrt 3 -2\pi}{6+2\pi\sqrt 3} = 2.03\> (2.03)$$

$$x_2= \frac{3\pi}{2} + \frac{2}{3\pi}= 4.92\>(4.91)$$

with the exact solutions given in parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

The integral of the absolute value of the velocity (i.e., the speed) over time:

$$\int\limits_{t=0}^4 \Big| \sin \left(\frac{\pi  t}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{2} \pi  t \cos \left(\frac{\pi t}{2}\right)\Big| dt = 8.44689.$$

[image]

Comment: Can we find the exact value of the integral?

Comment: @S.H.W [WolframAlpha can't do it](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+%7Csin%28pi*t%2F2%29%2Bpi*t%2F2*cos%28pi*t%2F2%29%7Cdt+from+0+to+4). Strictly speaking, that doesn't mean it can't be done, but it really lowers the odds.

Comment: @Arthur Is it possible to show that solving $\tan(x) = -x$ can't be done analytically?